# Angular `$.ajax` works but '$resource` - throws error how to sove this?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

In my app, I am trying to `POST` a request to the server. For this I am using `$resource` module.  However, when I try to post the object, I am getting an error as `TypeError: server.batchUpdate.save(...).$promise is not a function` and I am not able to post at all..

here is the code:

```
$scope.batchUpdate = function ( object ) {

        var newId = Number(object.Id);
        var newType = 'project';
        var newImportant = !object.IsImportant;

        var newobject = {

            "Id" : newId,
            "Type" : newType,
            "IsImportant"  : newImportant

        }

        console.log( newImportant, newId ); //updates

        server.batchUpdate.save({

            "updateImportant" :  JSON.stringify(newobject)

        })
        .$promise().then(function ( response ) {

            cosole.log( response );

        });

    }
```

I tried, but am unable to fix the issue at all. Later I tried using the direct `jQuery` `ajax` method, and it works fine.
here is the code:

```
$scope.batchUpdate = function ( object ) {

        var newId = Number(object.Id);
        var newType = 'project';
        var newImportant = !object.IsImportant;

        var newobject = {

            "Id" : newId,
            "Type" : newType,
            "IsImportant"  : newImportant

        }

        var param = { "updateImportant":newobject };

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://azvsptcsdev02:678/_vti_bin/CPMD.WEBSERVICE/ProjectInfoService.svc/UpdateImportantbyUser",
           data: JSON.stringify(param),
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           processData: true,
           success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
               console.log("success" + data, status, jqXHR ); /*getting response*/
           },
           error: function (xhr) {
               console.log('failure', xhr.responseText);
           }
       });


    }
```

But I prefer to use the `$resource` way. What do I need to do with my `$resource` post? any one help me please?

Comment: Is this in a controller or factory?  Did you inject the $resource service?

Comment: This is in controller, But the module `server` in the factory. using `$resource` module. i have no of `get()` methods using `$resource` without any issue. but i can't able to post

Comment: `$promise` is a property, not a method. Have you tried `.$promise.then(function ( response ) {...});`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to use `.$promise` as a function rather than a property.  Here is what you should look like, notice that the `.$promise` isn't invoked, but rather accessed (without parentheses).

```
$scope.batchUpdate = function (obj) {
    var newId = Number(obj.Id);
    var newType = 'project';
    var newImportant = !object.IsImportant;

    var newobject = {
        "Id" : newId,
        "Type" : newType,
        "IsImportant"  : newImportant
    };

    console.log(newImportant, newId); // Updates

    server.batchUpdate.save({
        "updateImportant" :  JSON.stringify(newobject)
    })
    .$promise.then(function(response) {
        cosole.log(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: Still I am getting this error : `POST http://azvsptcsdev02:678/_vti_bin/CPMD.WEBSERVICE/ProjectInfoService.svc/UpdateImportantbyUser 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: @user2024080 To the network tab! (press F12 and click network)